# Why is there a second solution to $5\sin(3x)−1 = 3$?

Tags: trigonometry

I cannot find how or why this,

$$5\sin(3x)−1 = 3$$

Has one of two solutions being this,

$$42.29 + n \times 120^\circ$$

I am lost on how to get this solution. I have found the other one, so I will not mention it.

Can someone help explain this and show how to get this solution? Thank you!

Comment: Human beings, please stop calling "equal" things that are not even of the same nature. It makes teaching logic to your children all the more difficult.

Comment: Ahahaha Alright, that makes sense. What should I say?

Comment: Something like "Why/(how you can find out that) this equation admits (blah blah) as a solution"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\sin 3x =\sin (180^\circ - 3x)= \frac45=\sin53.1^\circ$, which gives two sets of solutions,

$$3x=53.1^\circ + n\>360^\circ$$

$$3x=(180-53.1)^\circ + n\>360^\circ$$

with $n$ being integers. Thus, the complete sultions are

$$x= 17.7^\circ + n\>120^\circ,\>\>\>\>x= 42.3^\circ + n\>120^\circ$$

Comment: Ah-ha got it. You take the inverse of the first sin to get the angle of the first triangle. And you take the 180 - the angle you previously got to get the angle of the second triangle in the unit circle. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: @Compilerv2 - That is correct. Keep in mind trig functions all have 2 sets of solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your equation as $$\sin 3x=\frac45,$$ and find one angle whose sine is $4/5.$ Call such an angle $\alpha$ (I can't be bothered to work this out explicitly here, since it's tangential to my main point). Then we have that $\sin \alpha=4/5.$ Thus we want to solve the equation $$\sin 3x-\sin\alpha=0,$$ or $$2\cos(3x+\alpha)/2\sin(3x-\alpha)/2=0,$$ which implies $$\cos(3x+\alpha)/2=0$$ or that $$\sin(3x-\alpha)/2=0.$$ Thus it follows that $$\frac{3x+\alpha}{2}=90°(2j+1),$$ or that $$\frac{3x-\alpha}{2}=180°k,$$ where $j,k$ are arbitrary integers. From these you may easily solve for $x.$

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$5\sin(3x)−1 = 3 \iff \sin(3x)=\frac45 $$

then, since $\arcsin y\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and $\sin \theta = \sin (\pi-\theta)$, we have the following (set of) solution(s)

- $3x=\arcsin\left(\frac45\right)+2k\pi \implies x=\frac13\arcsin\left(\frac45\right)+\frac23k\pi$

which is the one you probably have already found and also this one

- $3x=\pi -\arcsin\left(\frac45\right)+2k\pi\implies x=\frac \pi 3-\frac13\arcsin\left(\frac45\right)+\frac23k\pi$

The key point is that $\arcsin$ function only returns values between $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ therefore we are loosing a (set of) solution(s) in the interval $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$. For example

$$\arcsin \frac {\sqrt2} 2=\frac \pi 4$$

and indeed $\sin \frac \pi 4 =\frac{\sqrt2} 2$ but also  $\sin \left(\pi-\frac \pi 4 \right)=\frac{\sqrt2} 2$.